# ML.NET/AI Read Document / Document Segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

I am attempting to read the structure and information within the structure of documents (or images, for simplicity - I can convert pdf's to jpeg) which vary greatly in structure.

Example: an invoice or a form. I would like to be able to segment each "segment" of information and read it. Although this could be done separately using OCR (this is not a problem for me), however, the dynamic segmentation is. Given that every document is going to be different, I need to build something which can segment dynamically. I'm not sure what technology would best achieve this. I am hoping to be able to use ML.NET in conjunction with a certain pre-trained model that I am hoping is available.

A very simplistic example might be:
[image: Example]

The information I would like to extract from the image above is:

```
{
    "Segments" : {
                     "Paragraph" : { "Text": "Lorem Ipsum", "Position": "X=123, Y=123" },
                     "TextBox" : { "Label": "LabelText XYZ-1", "InnerText" = "XYZ-1", "Position" : "X=123, Y=123" },
                     "TextBox" : { "Label": "LabelText XYZ-2", "InnerText" = "XYZ-2", "Position" : "X=123, Y=123" },
                     "TextBox" : { "Label": "LabelText XYZ-3", "InnerText" = "XYZ-3", "Position" : "X=123, Y=123" },
    }
}
```

I have tested ML.NET's Image Classification and Object Detection but they definitely do not seem to be up to this, despite this task seeming much more simple.

Would this be achievable using ML.NET? Please explain :)

Comment: Have you tried the Custom Vision service? It supports object detection and once you train a model you can export it to ONNX that ML.NET can then use to make predictions.

Comment: @Jon Thank you! Do you know if it is possible for an ML model to (in addition to locate the "segments" of text) recognize characters and convert to text?

Comment: Might be best to use a second model to recognize the characters and output the text instead of trying to put them into one model.